# Django InlineAdmin for ManyToMany field which doesn't have an explicitly named through

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I have two models, with `ManyToMany` relationships:

`App1`:

```
class Foo:
    fld = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

`App2`:

```
class Bar:
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, blank=True)
```

Now, on the admin view of `Bar`, I'd like to present `foos`. I cannot simply list `foos` as a ManyToMany field, I get an error message.

So I try to do:

```
class BarFooInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar_foos

class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Bar
    inlines = [BarFooInline, ]

admin.site.register(Bar, BarAdmin)
```

I got the name `Bar_foos` by look into the Meta of Bar. `Bar.foos.through` yields that as a proper `models.Bar_foos`. But since I didn't explicitly name the through, it's not really in the `models.py`, so I cannot import that. What should I do?

I don't want to create a through now, because I already have a whole bunch of association information in the table, and I have a feeling that wouldn't be magically data migrated into the newly named association entity's table (https://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2013/07/28/migrate-django-manytomany-field-to-manytomany-through-with-south/).

Also, I cannot move the `ManyToMany` field from `App2` to `App1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BarFooInline(admin.TabularInine):
    models = Bar.foos.through

class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Bar
    inlines = [BarFooInline]
    exclude = ['foos']
```

[Working with many-to-many models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Comment: Yes, it compiles that way! It's another thing that there are many objects, that the MySQL Client runs out of memory, so I have to find some other solution.